# Dynamic Variable Name: Concatenate Macro Define With Text

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to join a Macro Define with regular text?

For example;

```
#define T_NAME      Text_Int       
#define MAP_KEYS    T_NAME _Map_Keys      // defined in a separate header file "a.h"

// I am hoping MAP_KEYS = Text_Int_Map_Keys
```

So I can then go:

```
#undef T_NAME
#undef MAP_KEYS
#define T_NAME      Text_Real       
#define MAP_KEYS    T_NAME _Map_Keys

#undef T_NAME
#undef MAP_KEYS
#define T_NAME      Text_Short       
#define MAP_KEYS    T_NAME _Map_Keys
```

Comment: Why using a macro? Preprocessor processes your `#define`'s with a simple text replacement from your arguments. That doesn't look to be the appropriate approach for your actual problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `CAT` macro:

```
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define CAT_(x, y) x ## y

#define T_NAME      Text_Int 
#define MAP_KEYS    CAT(T_NAME, _MAP_KEYS)
```

then

```
MAP_KEYS
```

will expand to `Text_Int_Map_Keys`.

The indirection is needed as a normal operand for `##` is not expanded before pasting.